# Extract numbers in one column and add to another, if more than one number add them with a patter (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
CLIENT BENEFIT | SPECIFIC BENEFIT (EX. 15%, CPA) | NOTES
Client Sav     |                                 | a & string 10 some characters %&/
Client Sav     |                                 | a number 25 / another number 5 random stuff /(%
Client Sav     |                                 | hi 5
```

I want to extrapolate the numbers in the NOTES column adn add them in  SPECIFIC BENEFIT (EX. 15%, CPA). If there is more than one number the format should follow the following output number% / number%.
My expected output is then:

```
CLIENT BENEFIT | SPECIFIC BENEFIT (EX. 15%, CPA) | NOTES
Client Sav     |  10                             | a & string 10 some characters %&/
Client Sav     |  25% / 5%                       | a number 25 / another number 5 random stuff /(%
Client Sav     |  5                              | hi 5
```

How can I do it in Python?

Comment: Please add the code you tried to the question, explain what went wrong and what you did to solve the **problem**. What is the *problem*, by the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick solution using a couple of list comprehensions and a regular expression.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'CLIENT BENEFIT':['Client Sav']*3,
    'SPECIFIC BENEFIT (EX. 15%, CPA)':['']*3,
    'NOTES':['a & string 10 some characters %&/',
             'a number 25 / another number 5 random stuff /(%',
             'hi 5']})

df['SPECIFIC BENEFIT (EX. 15%, CPA)'] = [''.join(l) if len(l) < 2 else ('% / '.join(l) + '%') for l in [re.findall(r'-?\d+\.?\d*', s) for s in df['NOTES']]]

print(df[['CLIENT BENEFIT', 'SPECIFIC BENEFIT (EX. 15%, CPA)']])
```

Output:

```
  CLIENT BENEFIT SPECIFIC BENEFIT (EX. 15%, CPA)
0     Client Sav                              10
1     Client Sav                        25% / 5%
2     Client Sav                               5
```